# form send method GET and htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have cool uri in format

```
page.com/par1/par2/par3
```

But on this page is form, that send data with GET method, so I get again

```
page.com/?p1=par1&p2=par2&p3=par3
```

Maybe form has to have send data to some script(action="redirect.php"), that make cool uri for me?

```
header("Location: http://www.server.com/$_GET[p1]/$_GET[p2]/$_GET[p2]");
```

Is there any another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution is better than this, but you could utilize some jQuery/javascript that would redirect you to a URL that you built in that format. This probably isn't 100% valid javascript, but something like this would work:

Assuming that the fields holding the parameters have the IDs of par1, par2, and par3:

```
function fakeSubmit() {
    var coolURL = "http://page.com/" + $("#par1").val() + "/" +  
                  $("#par2").val() + "/" +  $("#par3").val() + "/";
    window.location.href = coolURL;
}
```

Then just have your button call that when it's clicked:

```
<input type="button" onclick="fakeSubmit()" value="Click Me!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify the "action" tag of your "form" with a javascript funcion based on the values of your form fields.

You can fire the javascript function by means of the "onsubmit()" method.